# SQL Query - Separating or batch excluding results based on a parameter

Tags: mysql, sql

So here's what I'm trying to accomplish.

From my database I am pulling Date, Invoice#, Customer Name, State, and Invoice total amount. Within the "invoice_details" table, I'm looking at a column called "description" for entries with the keyword tax (via "%Tax%"). Each invoice may have several entries in the 'description' column as each item listed on the invoice gets a description.

For invoices that were charged sales tax: an item is added to the invoice just for that tax charged. What I want to do is query in a way that will look to see if a particular Invoice# (or rowid in the "Invoice" table) has an entry with "%Tax%", do not return any results from that Invoice# (again, or rowid), including it's other lines of 'description' that do not relate to the tax charged.

In other words, searching all description column entries, of which multiple exist for each Invoice # - but exclude all entries of an Invoice# if one of its 'description' entries contain "%Tax%".

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL-Server? You tagged both, but they are not the same thing.

Comment: add a subquery in your `WHERE` using `NOT IN()` to filter out your rows -ie. `WHERE rowid NOT IN (SELECT rowid FROM yourTable WHERE description LIKE "%Tax%")`.

Comment: Sounds like bad design.  If you can't change the whole thing how about appending a meaningful column to what is there?

Comment: Oops, it is mySQL @Sean, "sql-server" was a recommended tag I blindly chose. Sorry about that

Comment: @ficuscr yes the design is unfortunate, it's a result of how the information from a previous database was imported to this new one. We are moving to more streamlined data as best we can, but when looking back we still need to work with how the previous information was imported.

Comment: @RobertH I can relate.  Additive changes, complementary table, even a view possibly might help with performance if you need to do a lot of reads.  `NOT IN` and full table scans from `LIKE %%` queries are never good.

Comment: I tried out the subquery @Sean, while using NOT LIKE "%Tax%" inside the subquery successfully excluded all invoices WITHOUT tax, using LIKE still returned all invoices.

Comment: I think it's similar to the issue that I had with the simple LIKE clause. All invoices contain one or more entries in .description that do not have "Tax" in them. Only some invoices have an entry with Tax, in addition to other entries without it.

So when looking for Tax, it only finds some invoices. When looking for NOT Tax - it still finds all of them.

Also, the data for `.description` is in a table `invoice_details`, the invoice number and rowid are in the table `invoice`. Their relationship being: `invoice_details`.ref_invoice = `invoice`.rowid